# Up and down arrow visible on Keyboard Date Picker and Icon Missing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can anyone help with this issue that has happened using KeyboardDatePicker from MaterialUI?

[KeyboardDatePicker Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAHyY.png)

There is a visible up and down arrow that I can't seem to hide and also the actual date picker icon is no longer visible. This was working before (i.e. there was no up and down arrow and the date picker was fully visible) and has seemed to just randomly stop working? Inside the black circle in the image is where the date picker is and you can see that it is very faint and actually still clickable.

"

<KeyboardDatePicker style={{marginTop:"10px"}}
clearable
label="Date of birth"
value={dateOfBirth}
onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date, setDateOfBirth, "birth")}
minDate={new Date(1900, 0 ,1)}
format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>

"

Comment: Are you using MUI v5?

Comment: I'm using MUI v4 

"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",

Comment: Not reproducible: https://codesandbox.io/s/67053310-material-ui-datepicker-forked-k3wh6?file=/demo.tsx